# Запрет push в ветку master

Tags: git, github

Как сделать, чтобы обновить ветку **master** могли только путём **merge**.

Итого с веткой master могут выполняться только действия:
*merge*
*fetch*
*pull*

Сейчас же любой джуниор может "повесилить" всю команду. Да откатили, да наругали - но не он первый, не он последний.

Если на сервер залить какой-то скрипт проблема будет, то можно же наверно и локально устанавливать с bash'ем скрипт, который запретит делать "беду"

Comment: возможно, настало время воспользоваться *gitolite-ом*?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin состовьте ответ - отмечу пологающе. Пока, что я помню, что это серверная вещь, которая на github не прокатит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте модель пулл-реквестов («Fork + Pull») вместо модели «Общего репозитория»
(The Shared Repository Model).

Гитхаб рекомендует [Using pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)

Answer (score 1):

GitLab: Settings - Repository - Protected Branches(Expand) - Master: Allowed to push(No one)